# Angular Best Practices on $scope - when you're teaching newbies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm running an angular workshop in a few weeks, and am unsure whether to teach them about `$scope` or teach them the `controller as` syntax.

Moving forward to Angular 2.0, scopes are rid of. But `$scope` was a core part of my learning.

So my question is - moving forward, will you be preaching about `$scope` or `controller as`?

Comment: Like you said, `$scope` is going away in angular 2. I would say both are worth teaching for an angular 1.x course since they're going to run into each syntax out in the wild, but that `controller as` is the best practice for them to use in their own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are teaching Angular 1.x, they you will have to instil the understanding of `scope` and how they work in Angular, irrespective of whether you are planning to use `controller as` syntax. The understanding of digest cycle, scope hierarchy, isolated scope are essential in Angular 1.x.

What i will suggest is to start with teaching then about scope and build some initial samples using standard scope base binding and data sharing mechanism.

Then you can introduce `controller as` syntax and contrast it against scope usage and highlight why is it better than using `scopes` and how Angular 2 is getting rid of the concept of scope altogether.